# .NET Selenium Image download - 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, http-status-code-403

System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'

I am trying to download images from a web page using Selenium in C#. The web page seems to prevent direct downloads, and although I can manually download images by right-clicking on them, my Selenium code is encountering issues, possibly due to security policies or other restrictions.

I can download the images from the entire page with plug-ins in Chrome or manually by right-clicking the mouse, but I want to download them automatically in my application. Do you have different solutions for this?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    [Obsolete]
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("URL: ");
        string url = Console.ReadLine() ?? "";

        await DownloadImagesAsync(url);
    }

    [Obsolete]
    static async Task DownloadImagesAsync(string url)
    {
        string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string downloadFolder = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "DownloadedImages");

        if (!Directory.Exists(downloadFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadFolder);
        }

        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("user-agent=Mozilla/....");

        using var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        try
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

            var imageElements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("img"));

            using WebClient webClient = new();

            webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/....");

            Uri uri = new(url);
            string referer = $"{uri.Scheme}://{uri.Host}/";
            webClient.Headers.Add("Referer", referer);
            
            webClient.Headers.Add("Sec-Ch-Ua", "Not_A Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"120\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"120");
            webClient.Headers.Add("Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile", "?0");
            webClient.Headers.Add("Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform", "\"Windows\"");

            for (int i = 0; i < imageElements.Count; i++)
            {
                string fileName = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}_{i + 1}.jpg";

                try
                {
                    var imageElement = imageElements[i];

                    string imageUrl = imageElement.GetAttribute("src");

                    string filePath = Path.Combine(downloadFolder, fileName);

                    await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(imageUrl, filePath);

                    Console.WriteLine($"{fileName}");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{fileName} => Error: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
   }
}
```

This is the error I get during the DownloadFileTaskAsync process:
System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'

Comment: I would first try to download using Postman which will give better error messages.  Then once you get postman working check the Postman console to see all the HTTP Headers being using.  The modify your c# code to use same headers as Postman.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bot protection. You can try the following to bypass it:

1. Ensure you are using the latest user agent version
2. Enable cookies and try to set some before executing the request
3. Try to change a referer header
4. Try to set up some delay before downloading the image
5. Act like a human, not a bot